# How can we configure value.subject.name.strategy for schemas in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka producers, consumers and KStreams?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I would like to customize the naming strategy of the Avro schema subjects in Spring Cloud Stream Producers, Consumers and KStreams.

This would be done in Kafka with the properties `key.subject.name.strategy` and `value.subject.name.strategy` -> https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html#subject-name-strategy

In a native Kafka Producer this works:

```
private val producer: KafkaProducer<Int, Customer>

    init {
        val props = Properties()
        ...
        props[AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = "http://localhost:8081"
        props[AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY] = TopicRecordNameStrategy::class.java.name
        producer = KafkaProducer(props)
    }

    fun sendCustomerEvent(customer: Customer) {
        val record: ProducerRecord<Int, Customer> = ProducerRecord("customer", customer.id, customer)
        producer.send(record)
    }
```

However I cannot find how to do this in Spring Cloud Stream. So far I have tried this in a producer:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-customer-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          output:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key:
                  serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
                value:
                  subject:
                    name:
                      strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
```

Apparently Spring Cloud uses it's own subject naming strategy with the interface `org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.SubjectNamingStrategy` and only one subclass: `DefaultSubjectNamingStrategy`.

Is there declarative way of configuring `value.subject.name.strategy` or are we expected to provide our own `org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.SubjectNamingStrategy` implementation and the property `spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.subject-naming-strategy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer there's a [dedicated property](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_avro_schema_registry_client_message_converters), `spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.subjectNamingStrategy`, that allows to set up a different naming strategy **for Kafka producers**.

I contributed the [`org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.QualifiedSubjectNamingStrategy`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/cd0e3c1a3823a14d3ca3a678cb0f34f3ceb6faa6/schema-registry/spring-cloud-stream-schema-registry-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/schema/registry/avro/QualifiedSubjectNamingStrategy.java) that provides that functionality out of the box.

In the case of **Kafka Streams** and native serialization/deserialization (default behaviour from Spring Cloud Streams 3.0.0+) you have to use Confluent's implementation (`io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy`) and the native properties:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: shipping-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      ...
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              application:
                id: shipping-service
              ...
              value:
                subject:
                  name:
                    strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it in your properties as

```
spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.subjectNamingStrategy=MyStrategy
```

where MyStrategy is an implementation of the interface. For instance

```
object MyStrategy: SubjectNamingStrategy {
   override fun toSubject(schema: Schema): String = schema.fullName
}
```